# Perl Empty Strings inside Arrays

Tags: arrays, perl

I want to loop over an array of strings, but sometimes if the string is empty, it still gets added as an item.

```
my $forename = $service->getValue('forename');
my $surname = $service->getValue('surname');

my @selectedNames = ( $forename, $surname );

foreach my $name (@selectedNames) {
    # do something

    if ($trackedName) {
         # log the name
    } else {
         # log a FATAL
    }
}
```

If the string is empty for $surname, then it shouldn't loop the second time at all, but it always does. How do I prevent this?

Comment: What do you mean, "sometimes"? If you make an array out of `$forename` and `$surname`, it always has two elements.

Comment: So how do I ensure it only loops once if $surname is empty?

Comment: `my @selectedNames = grep {defined and length } ( $forename, $surname );`

Comment: @Сухой27 `grep { length } ...` is enough.

Comment: Yes, length is enough. perl 5.10 complains though https://stackoverflow.com/a/1481979/223226

Comment: Great. Feel free to put it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Concerning Frank Förster's response (I don't have enough reputation to reply directly):

Wouldn't grepping using `$_` also strip any numeric item with the value 0, and the string "0"? I realize you're not likely to get them as "surnames", but not being prepared for such an eventuality may lead to bugs that are hard to track.

---

Edit: Here's my solution (after prompting by PerlDuck):

```
my $forename = $service->getValue('forename');
my $surname = $service->getValue('surname');

my @selectedNames = ( $forename, $surname );

foreach my $name (@selectedNames) {
    next  if (not defined $name  or  $name eq '');

    # do something

    if ($trackedName) {
        # log the name
    } else {
        # log a FATAL
    }
}
```

Alternately you can just use the original code, but substitute

```
foreach my $name (@selectedNames)
```

with

```
foreach my $name (grep { defined and $_ ne '' } @selectedNames)
```

If you're worried your "empty" names may include stuff with just whitespace in them, you can use `$name =~ /^\s*$/` instead of `$name eq ''`.

Comment: I'd love to upvote this, but as it stands it's not a complete answer. And, yes, `"0"` and `0` would be skipped with the `grep {$_} @array` code.

Comment: Nice work.  `grep { defined $_ && /\S/ } @names` is an easy way to require non-whitespace elements in your filter.  You can also just say `grep {defined && /\S/} @names`, because $_ is assumed for `defined`.

Comment: Nice! `/\S/` is quite elegant. I rarely think to use the negative character class escapes - more often than not I end up using ridiculously complicated constructs with the positive ones, in the style of `/(?!\s)./`. I definitely need to work on this.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `next unless ($name);` as first line of your loop.

Perl handles the values `undef` and empty string (`''`) as false and will therefore enter the next loop.

```
my $forename = $service->getValue('forename');
my $surname = $service->getValue('surname');

my @selectedNames = ( $forename, $surname );

foreach my $name (@selectedNames) {
    next unless ($name);

    # do something

    if ($trackedName) {
         # log the name
    } else {
         # log a FATAL
    }
}
```

If you want to use grep to filter the list actually you neither need length nor defined: `grep { $_ } (@selectedNames)` would be enough. Therefore your code would look like

```
my $forename = $service->getValue('forename');
my $surname = $service->getValue('surname');

my @selectedNames = ( $forename, $surname );

foreach my $name (grep { $_ } @selectedNames) {
    # do something

    if ($trackedName) {
         # log the name
    } else {
         # log a FATAL
    }
}
```